# Кол-во и сумма элементов массива в массиве

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть массив `bets`

```
  var bets = [
                  {name: "Генадий", img: "img", value: 100, items: [
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 100, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 110, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 120, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010}] },
                  {name: "Генадий", img: "img", value: 100, items: [
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 100, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 110, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 120, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010}] },
                  {name: "Генадий", img: "img", value: 100, items: [
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 100, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 110, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
                    {img: "skin_img", price: 120, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010}] }];
```

В нем есть еще один массив `items`

Есть цикл который выводит значения с массива

```
for(var key in bets) {
          var b = bets[key];
          console.log(b);
}
```

Как посчитать сумму значение `price` в подмассиве `items`? А так же как посчитать кол-во элементов в этом массиве. Соответственно на выход я должен получить такие значения: `(price summ = 330, items length = 3)`

Пробовал делать так:

```
var items_amount = 0;
for(var key in bets) {
              var b = bets[key];
              console.log(b);
              items_amount += bets[key].items.length;
              console.log(items_amount);
    }
```

Но результат получается 3,6,9.. и тд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это всё делается с помощью простых циклов.

Сделал вывод данных в консоль, а вы уже используйте эти данные как вам нужно:

```js
var bets = [
    {
        name: "Генадий", img: "img", value: 100, 
        items: [
          {img: "skin_img", price: 100, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
          {img: "skin_img", price: 110, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
          {img: "skin_img", price: 120, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010}
        ] 
    },
    {
        name: "Генадий", img: "img", value: 100, 
        items: 
        [
            {img: "skin_img", price: 100, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
            {img: "skin_img", price: 110, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
            {img: "skin_img", price: 120, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010}
        ] 
    },
    {
        name: "Генадий", img: "img", value: 100, 
        items: 
        [
        {img: "skin_img", price: 100, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
        {img: "skin_img", price: 110, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010},
        {img: "skin_img", price: 120, color: "color", bot_steamid:111010}
        ] 
    }
];

function sum( items ) {
  var sum = 0;
  for( var key in items ) {
    var item = items[key];
    sum += item.price;
  }
  return sum;
}

for( var key in bets) {
    var item = bets[key];
    console.log('items length: ' + item.items.length);
    console.log('price sum: ' + sum(item.items));
    console.log('-----');
}
```